# Specify assembly in WPF ResourceDictionary to solve Ambiguous type reference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a ResourceDictionary file like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns:vsm ="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Used in this page

```
<Page xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" 
      x:Class="MyProject.GUI.MenuPage"

      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

      ....

      <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/GUI/ResourcesDictionary.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </Page.Resources>

      ....
</Page>
```

This page uses a wpf toolkit component, the autocompletebox, so I have the WPFToolkit library (last version available [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)) as a project reference. It works fine in running time, but I get this error in the visual studio designer:

> Ambiguous type reference. A type named 'VisualState' occurs in at
>   least two namespaces, 'System.Windows' and 'System.Windows'. Consider
>   adjusting the assembly XmlnsDefinition attributes.

This occurs in the first line of the ResourceDictionary file (I dont use the toolkit in this file). Looking over other questions in SO, I see that there are classes in the toolkit with the same namespace that are now incorporated to the framework 4.0, so I guess I need to specify the assembly in the ResourceDictionary so it doesn't import the classes in the toolkit. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the alias for the assembly, if that is no problem to you.

Set this property on the reference in Visual Studio

[image: alias property]